# Why does pd.cut produce NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

Why does `pd.cut` produce `NaN` values ?

Input

```
s = pd.Series(np.arange(6))
df = pd.DataFrame({'Bin': pd.cut(s, [105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130]),
                   'Frequency': [2,5,6,8,8,1]})
df
```

Output

[image]

Expected output

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the values (0, 1, 2, ..) of the Series `s` doesn't fit the bins when you [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html).

You can instead make an [`IntervalIndex.from_breaks`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.from_breaks.html) :

```
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks([105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130, 135])

df = pd.DataFrame({"Bin": idx, "Frequency": [2,5,6,8,8,1]})
```

Output :

```
print(df)

          Bin  Frequency
0  (105, 110]          2
1  (110, 115]          5
2  (115, 120]          6
3  (120, 125]          8
4  (125, 130]          8
5  (130, 135]          1

[6 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: it is possible to use pd.cut() method to achieve the same output as your answer ?

Comment: You already used it and you got `NaN`. So, I would say no.

Comment: okay thanks '''